# Can I fly in and out of Australia with an unpaid fire related fine?

Tags: australia, fines

So a few months ago I was given a $650 fine for "lighting a fire in a national park" and I remember the police officers mentioning something about us breaking a federal law.

Now I disputed the fine as I did not light any fire and was falsely accused and after some time I was asked in an email to provide *full contact info* of the person who lit the fire in a statutory declaration. Now I don't have any of these details so I tried to contact the Infringement Notice person I was in contact with via phone and email and was ghosted. It is now past the date they gave me and I am about to go on holiday to New Zealand.

Am I going to face any issues at the airport over this?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: Please specify the type of layover.

Comment: Where is the national park?  National park offences are typically state offences, unless the park is located in a federal territory (such as the Australian Capital Territory).

Comment: Where are you flying from? transiting in Syd/ Mel? Cbr? Is this is in the same state as teh offence? Just transiting or stopping over?